# Difficulty in printing total number of rows in php MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch 5 random followers of the current users. And then I'll fetch all the posted by the 5 random followers but I'm having trouble doing this. I want to print the total number of rows, but I'm getting individual rows posted by each follower.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","robin","mypassword");
mysql_select_db("my_db");

//Get list of posts to be paginated
$sql = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM followers 
    WHERE being_followed = '".$_SESSION['username']."' LIMIT 5"
);

while($followers = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $my_followers = $followers['follower_username'];
    $new_query    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE poster = '$my_follower'");
    while($the_posts = mysql_fetch_array($new_query)){
        $total_posts = mysql_num_rows($new_query);
        $echo $total_posts;
        $poster = $the_posts['poster'];
        $the_post = $the_posts['the_post'];
        echo $poster;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $the_post;
        echo "<p>";
    }
}
?>
```

The above code print:

3 Robin
hi guys this is robin

3 Robin
I'm loving it

3 Robin
Where's he?

2 Sam 
going through changes

2 Sam
where's da party 2nite

But that's not what I want. I simply want to print the total number of posts.
Please help me out guys.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your expected output

Comment: It first prints total number of rows i.e. 5 and then it prints each post with its poster

Comment: update your question with expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$totalPosts = 0;
while($followers = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $my_follower  = $followers['follower_username'];
    $new_query    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE poster = '$my_follower'");
    $num_rows     = mysql_num_rows($new_query);
    $totalPosts   += $num_rows;
    echo $num_rows." ".$my_follower."<br/>";
}

echo $totalPosts ;
```

It will output something like:

> 3 Robin
>   2 Sam

Updated to include total number of posts

Comment: No...actually I want total number of rows to be printed. In this example I want 5 to be printed i.e. 3 posts of Robin and 2 posts of Sam,

Comment: The updated code is printing total number of rows, unfortunately it is printing the incorrect number. There aren't more than 20 posts in the table but the code is printing 61 total rows. Some of the posts are being printed again and again. Probably something is wrong with the while loop, it might be printing the posts repeatedly.